# How to build my Yii2 Codeception test in Linux

Tags: yii2, codeception

I have a Yii2 project in my centos server and also codeception installed.
But when I enter command with `codecept`, it always return `codecept: command not found`. But with the same project & same code in window, it is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed Codeception using Composer then run `./vendor/bin/codecept`.
If you downloaded phar file, then you have to move it to some directory which belongs to PATH or use a full path to it.
If codecept.phar file is downloaded to current directory, you have to use `./` prefix to execute it - `./codecept` or `./codecept.phar` depending on filename.